# Cmake on OSX Yosemite 10.10.3 - GLEW: package 'gl' not found

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, glew, osx-yosemite

A while ago I decided to learn and delve myself in Cmake and ran into some annoying issues.

Following some tutorials (involving opengl and glew), I built a basic application that ran fine on a windows emulated machine but at a specific moment, emulation wouldn't just do the trick anymore and I switched to Xcode and also Cmake.

So I set up a basic folder structure:

```
build
CMakeLists.txt
inc
lib
src
```

lib folder includes the folders:

```
glew
glfw
```

Which are unzipped straight from their original downloads (including a CMakeLists.txt file and all)

To include the libs I used these 2 lines in my root CMakeLists.txt but only with glew I got a "'gl' not found" error

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(lib/glfw)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(lib/glew)
```

When building with cmake I got this output which I wasn't very happy about :(

```
Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
Using Cocoa for window creation
Using NSGL for context creation
Building GLFW only for the native architecture
checking for module 'gl'
  package 'gl' not found
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:340 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:502 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  lib/glew/CMakeLists.txt:26 (pkg_check_modules)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/Makkura/Dropbox/PROGRAMMING/CPLUSPLUS_SANDBOX/CMAKE/SPARKY/build/Xcode/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I assume there is something wrong with the CMakeLists.txt file in the GLEW folder. I can see specific actions for windows and linux but I can't see anything specified for osx systems.

```
project(GLEW)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4)

if(COMMAND cmake_policy)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0003 NEW)
endif(COMMAND cmake_policy)

set(GLEW_VERSION "1.11.0")

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Windows")
    set(GLEW_LIB_NAME glew32)
else(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Windows")
    set(GLEW_LIB_NAME GLEW)
    set(DLL_PREFIX lib)
endif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Windows")

#
# All platforms need OpenGL
#

include(FindPkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules( OpenGL REQUIRED gl )

#
# Linux needs X11
#

if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
    find_package(X11 REQUIRED)
endif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CFLAGS} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -DGLEW_BUILD -DGLEW_NO_GLU -O2 -Wall -W" )

include_directories( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include )

add_library(GLEW_static STATIC src/glew.c )
add_library(GLEW_shared SHARED src/glew.c )
set_target_properties(GLEW_static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ${GLEW_LIB_NAME} PREFIX lib)
set_target_properties(GLEW_shared PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ${GLEW_LIB_NAME} PREFIX "${DLL_PREFIX}")
target_link_libraries(GLEW_shared ${OpenGL_LDFLAGS})

add_library(GLEW_MX_static STATIC src/glew.c )
add_library(GLEW_MX_shared SHARED src/glew.c )
set_target_properties(GLEW_MX_static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ${GLEW_LIB_NAME}mx COMPILE_FLAGS "-DGLEW_MX" PREFIX lib)
set_target_properties(GLEW_MX_shared PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ${GLEW_LIB_NAME}mx COMPILE_FLAGS "-DGLEW_MX" PREFIX "${DLL_PREFIX}")
target_link_libraries(GLEW_MX_shared ${OpenGL_LDFLAGS})

add_executable(glewinfo src/glewinfo.c)
target_link_libraries(glewinfo GLEW_shared ${OpenGL_LDFLAGS})

if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
    target_link_libraries(glewinfo ${X11_LIBRARIES})
endif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")

add_executable(visualinfo src/visualinfo.c)
target_link_libraries(visualinfo GLEW_shared ${OpenGL_LDFLAGS})

if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
    target_link_libraries(visualinfo ${X11_LIBRARIES})
endif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")

install(
    TARGETS
        GLEW_static
        GLEW_shared
        GLEW_MX_static
        GLEW_MX_shared
        glewinfo
        visualinfo
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
)

install(CODE "execute_process( COMMAND bash -x -c \"sed -e 's%@prefix@%${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}%g' -e 's%@exec_prefix@%\\\${prefix}%g' -e 's%@libdir@%\\\${prefix}/lib%g' -e 's%@includedir@%\\\${prefix}/include%g' -e 's/\@version\@/${GLEW_VERSION}/g' -e 's/\@cflags\@//g' -e 's/\@libname\@/${GLEW_LIB_NAME}/g' -e 's|@requireslib@|glu|g' < ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/glew.pc.in > ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/glew.pc\" )" )
install(CODE "execute_process( COMMAND bash -x -c \"sed -e 's%@prefix@%${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}%g' -e 's%@exec_prefix@%\\\${prefix}%g' -e 's%@libdir@%\\\${prefix}/lib%g' -e 's%@includedir@%\\\${prefix}/include%g' -e 's/\@version\@/${GLEW_VERSION}/g' -e 's/\@cflags\@/-DGLEW_MX/g' -e 's/\@libname\@/${GLEW_LIB_NAME}mx/g' -e 's|@requireslib@|glu|g' < ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/glew.pc.in > ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/glewmx.pc\" )" )

install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/glew.pc ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/glewmx.pc DESTINATION lib/pkgconfig)
```

As long as I don't get this problem solved I can't continue with my development. I've been searching for similar issues for days but I can't find any definitive solution. Has anyone encountered a similar problem like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, what fails is `pkg-config`, trying to find the `gl` package, i.e. a `gl.pc` configuration file.
I have no idea where that one's supposed to be and there seems to be no documentation regarding it, as well as no reports of anyone ever even trying this.
I can only assume that the goal of this is to reference the OpenGL framework in `/System/Library/Frameworks`, but, at least on my machine, there is no `gl.pc` anywhere to be found. 
Also, trying to build glew with

```
export CC='clang'
export CXX='clang++'
cd glew
cmake .
make
```

gives me the same error you get.

However, I was able to craft my own `gl.pc`:

```
PACKAGE=GL

Name: OpenGL
Description: OpenGL
Version: 11.1.1
Cflags: -framework OpenGL -framework AGL
Libs: -Wl,-framework,OpenGL,-framework,AGL
```

(The AGL framework is part of the OpenGL framework.)
Putting this file in a location where `pkg-config` would find it, I was able to actually build glew.

Since you are building your own cmake thingy, you might not want to put this file in `/usr/share/pkgconfig` but rather have it somewhere in your project folder and set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` accordingly.
E.g. if you put `gl.pc` in `<your project>/pkgconfig`, add this to the top of your CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/pkgconfig)
```

Again, I have no idea whether or not this is the way anything's supposed to be done, but it works (at least for me).

Comment: Well if I'm doing things the hard way you can always mention it. The idea was that regardless of what is installed on your machine, you would always be able to build the entire project without installing several developer libs on your machine. Oh and btw I found a gl.pc on my machine at /opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig containing the following code.
`prefix=/opt/X11
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=/opt/X11/lib
includedir=/opt/X11/include

Name: gl
Description: Mesa OpenGL library
Requires.private: 
Version: 8.0.4
Libs: -L${libdir} -lGL
Libs.private: 
Cflags: -I${includedir} 
glx_tls: no`

Comment: I don't have X11 installed at the moment, so I don't have the `/opt` directory. But the frameworks (which are in `/System/Library/Frameworks`) are part of the OS, so no developer libs are required. The only requirement (besides `cmake`/`make` ofc) is `pkg-config`, but that's required by glew.

Comment: Ohw I thought pkg-config was a module of cmake or something. I guess I should download it then and take it for a spin.

Comment: I installed pkg-config, using this article as a guide. http://www.fantageek.com/318/install-pkg-config-for-mac-osx/
Nothing special happened tho when building in the cmake-gui again.

Comment: Well you obviously had pkg-config already, otherwise you would've received an error message like `pkg-config tool not found`. I'm just saying that it's a requirement that is not installed by default.

Comment: Oh that's annoying ... there goes the portable part of my cmake project. Wasn't even aware I had pkg-config. There must be a way to ommit pkg-config from my project by using precompiled libraries.

I tried using your gl.pc trick too, but was unable to find a PKG_CONFIG_PATH

If you want you can always take a look at what I already have:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/clyy7ibpsk4rjjv/SPARKY.zip?dl=0

Comment: Add this to the top of your CMakeLists.txt: `set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/pkgconfig)` and place your `gl.pc` in `SPARKY/pkgconfig`.

Comment: Thanks allot for the help. This solved the issue with CMake but now I'm having more trouble with XCode (which I'm not that experienced with). I guess I'll open another question for that though since this topic was only about the CMake part of it.