# XCode Project - ld: library not found for -llib

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake, glew

Recently I ran into a CMake problem that can be found in this thread:

[Cmake on OSX Yosemite 10.10.3 - GLEW: package 'gl' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457534/cmake-on-osx-yosemite-10-10-3-glew-package-gl-not-found)

Eventually it got solved, maybe partly due to my inexperience in XCode and CMake. (I mainly used visual studio to compile projects in the past.)

After the alteration in the linked thread I got warning about my GLEW libs in CMake

**(Is this something I should be worried about or is it not important?)**:

```
MACOSX_RPATH is not specified for the following targets:

   GLEW_MX_shared
   GLEW_shared
```

I simply ignored it and tried to compile my project in XCode with the ALL_BUILD target selected. In the sparky target it said the include files in main could not be found so I added the .h files into the inc folder of my project.

When I compiled again the compiler started complaining again

(**I don't know what this error means and how I can fix it.**):

```
ld: library not found for -llib
```

Googled it for the entire day now and I can't find anything to solve this issue.

It's so frustrating working with XCode as an IDE but I really want to learn more about different platforms and their most popular IDE's so I can make multi platform applications from the start instead of porting it afterwards.

And if it matters I am using OSX Yosemite 10.10.3.

To make my issue easier to understand, I've put a zip of my project on my dropbox. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xnrh90kuih9ia5a/SPARKY%202.zip?dl=0

Feel free to ask questions if I explained things to briefly and again, thanks to everyone who contributes here. I really learned allot after discovering these forums.

**EDIT: Alright I booted up my windows machine, generated a visual studio environment and tried to build it on there. Seems that the same problem also happens here. I looked at the linker attributes/flags and saw a lib.lib file added to the linking process which doesn't look right at all.**

When removing the file, the error disappeared and many others arrived! (Which are simply solved by linking the appropriate libs so I wont handle those here.)

I misunderstood the error on my mac and thought it was referring to a random library which I needed to hunt down but actually it's a inconsistency in one of my CMake files.

EDIT2: Now I only have to find out where the lib.lib comes from and how I can ditch the flags from the project so I can generate my environment and build right away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So moral of the story. Sometimes the solution is right in front of you and still ends up more like looking for a needle in a haystack.

I removed the following from my root CMakeLists.txt file and the random lib.lib library was gone from my generated projects

```
SET( PROJ_LIBRARIES "lib" )
```

I thought this added a folder containing libraries but actually what it did was adding another flag for a specific library because this variable was being fed to:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( ${PROJ_NAME} ${PROJ_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} )
```